# Install GitLab on Subdomain

Tags: bash, centos, gitlab, yum

I am trying to install GitLab on a subdomain. I am not very familiar with web servers and stuff, only very little knowledge. I am currently connected to the subdomain via `ssh admin@mysite.com` on the Mac's Terminal. Then I `ls` to the subdomain's folder. Question is if I execute:

```
curl -O https://downloads-packages.s3.amazonaws.com/centos-6.5/gitlab-7.4.3_omnibus.5.1.0.ci-1.el6.x86_64.rpm
sudo yum install openssh-server
sudo yum install postfix
sudo yum install cronie
sudo service postfix start
sudo chkconfig postfix on
sudo rpm -i gitlab-7.4.3_omnibus.5.1.0.ci-1.el6.x86_64.rpm
```

on the current folder. Will GitLab be installed or downloaded only in the current folder or will other subdomains and folders of the site be affected?

Is there a way to test `yum install` first on the current directory?

Answer (score 12):

The Omnibus/RPM version of Gitlab will install gitlab to the /opt/gitlab directory.
If you want to check the files that will be installed by an RPM package you can do so with:

```
rpm -qlp gitlab-7.4.3_omnibus.5.1.0.ci-1.el6.x86_64.rpm
```

After you install the RPM with "rpm -ivh gitlab*.rpm" you configure the URL/subdomain using the:

```
/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb
```

file.
After amending the gitlab.rb file you can start gitlab with:

```
gitlab-ctl start
```

Or restart it with:

```
gitlab-ctl restart
```

You can configure the web address & port that gitlab/nginx listens on using the external_url parameter in the gitlab.rb file:

```
external_url "https://gitlab.mydomain.com"
```

If you already have a webserver (such as Apache) using port 80 or port 443 then you might want to ask gitlab/nginx to listen on a port other than 80 or 443 with:

```
external_url "https://gitlab.mydomain.com:8443"
```

You can check if anything is listening on particular ports using:

```
netstat -luntap | grep LISTEN
```

Comment: So will it install files outside of my subdomain directory? Because I have files in the main domain and other subdomains that I don't wanna mess up.

Comment: `gitlabctl-restart` should be `gitlab-ctl restart`

Comment: And `gitlab-ctl restart` does not do the job here. You need to run `gitlab-ctl reconfigure`. (See https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/master/doc/settings/configuration.md#configuring-the-external-url-for-gitlab.)

Comment: I get the following error: `Validation failed for domain subdomain.example.com` any idea why?